# How to use doxygen in xcode 4.6?

Tags: objective-c

I tried to use doxygen in Xcode 4.6 to document the source code written in objective c,
and followed these links:

[Link1](http://www.doxygen.nl/), [Link2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htFKHP4xdTs)

but these links deal with the older xcode versions.
please help me use doxygen in xcode 4.6 (latest).

Answer (score 0):

I use an external build system target.  In the Info tab, set the tool to

```
/Applications/Doxygen.app/Contents/Resources/doxygen
```

(or wherever you have Doxygen installed)

and the argument to

```
Doxyfile
```

Or where you have put the config file.

Comment: Thank you very much, i got the expected result. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a better alternative for Apple environement to Doxygen : [Appledoc](http://gentlebytes.com/appledoc/)